How to attach a google tab (already opened) to a python script
I would like to open to attach a python script to a google tab already opened.
Basically, my objective is to do some actions on the page and then get the source code.
I already tried to use selenium as I found on another topic, like this :
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('debuggerAddress', 'localhost:9014')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

# Get the source code of the current page
source_code = driver.page_source

But when I try to launch it, nothing append. It seams blocked on this line :
options.add_experimental_option('debuggerAddress', 'localhost:9014')

Maybe I put the wrong port ? I don't know.
Someone have another way to attache a python script to an opened google tab, or to solve the "error".


Close all instances of Chrome.
Open a CMD.
Start Chrome with remote debugging port running one of these commands depending on your OS.

Windows:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9014

MacOS:
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9014

Linux:
google-chrome --remote-debugging-port=9014

Make sure:

Make sure that ChromeDriver and Chrome versions are compatible.
Make sure that ChromeDriver is in your system's PATH.

Here's the script:
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('debuggerAddress', 'localhost:9014')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
source_code = driver.page_source
print(source_code)

